# Python Selenium send_keys(KEYS ENTER) not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently on this website. https://www.zoocasa.com/
I am trying to search a city then press enter for it to load to the next page but it's not working.

This is what I have in my code so far.

```
inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
for character in 'Toronto':
    inputElement.send_keys(character)
    time.sleep(0.1)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I also tried Keys.RETURN and that doesn't seem to be working as well. Any help would be great

Edit: If you try to go to the website, type in a city and then press ENTER, it would work.

Comment: @M.Soyturk I just want the characters to show up slowly.

Comment: Ok. You should simply send Keys.ENTER to the Search button on the page instead of the input element. Edit: I just realized that you should select the city before you click the search button. When you write a city name the website shows you the options that you can select. You should select the appropriate one and then click search button by sending Keys.ENTER

Comment: @M.Soyturk Thank you so much. Got it working now. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't press the 'enter' key but be more specific and 'click' the search button.
E.g.

```py
# Might be worth importing this:
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
# Tries to click the button
try:
    search_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]")[0]
    search_button.click()
    # If you see this in console, the button has been clicked
    print("Button clicked")
except NoSuchElementException:
    # If you see this, the button has not been found / clicked
    print("No button found")
```